# How could I prevent inputs from shuffling to a wrong location when showing info boxes using Bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to create a form which should show an alert:

[image: Basic form]

When hitting the button control next to the input control, it should show an alert. The alert appears correctly, however, the input controls following after shuffle to a wrong location:

[image: Inputs shuffling]

I would like to see the following happen:

[image: Prevent shuffle]

How could I prevent the shuffling of input controls on the left to the right side? Keep in mind that in the solution I would like the order of input controls to be the same when resizing to smaller screen size.

This is what I tried so far in code:

```js
function toggleInfo(ele) {
  if (ele.style.display === "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>One</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggleInfo(foo_id)">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;" id="foo_id">
    <strong>Info: </strong> Message.
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Two</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Three</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Four</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Five</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried wrapping up every two `col-md-6` elements in a `<div>` element to see if these would keep sticking together. This was not the case:

```js
function toggleInfo(ele) {
  if (ele.style.display === "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div><!-- Not working -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>One</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggleInfo(foo_id)">
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;" id="foo_id">
      <strong>Info: </strong> Message.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Two</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div><!-- End of change I tried -->

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Three</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Four</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Five</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What could I do to fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing `row` class and also you required to update your `DOM` check snippet.

```js
function toggleInfo(ele) {
  if (ele.style.display === "none") {
    ele.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    ele.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<div class="row">
  <!-- Not working -->
  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>One</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggleInfo(foo_id)">
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;" id="foo_id">
      <strong>Info: </strong> Message.
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Two</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            -
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
<!-- End of change I tried -->
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Three</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Four</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Five</label>
    <div class="input-group">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" />
      <div class="input-group-btn">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ah yes, I thought the column wouldn't be required for the fiddle in order find a solution. Simply placing the rows correctly solved my problem, though I had the idea/assumption that would not fix it.

Answer (score 1):

u need to wrap 2 col-md-6 divs in a row like this:

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>One</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggleInfo(foo_id)">
            -
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;" id="foo_id">
        <strong>Info: </strong> Message.
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
        <label>Two</label>
        <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            -
            </button>
        </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should place `<div class="container-fluid"><div class="row" /></div></div>` as parent to your child `<div class="col-md-6" />`

The important part is `<div class="row"> /*child col */</div>`

See sample snippets below:

```
<div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label>One</label>
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" />
            <div class="input-group-btn">
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="toggleInfo(foo_id)">
              -
            </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="alert alert-info" style="display: none;" id="foo_id">
          <strong>Info: </strong> Message.
        </div>
      </div>

  <div class="col-md-6">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label>Two</label>
      <div class="input-group">
        <input type="text" class="form-control" />
        <div class="input-group-btn">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
          -
        </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Tweak here: https://codepen.io/kenneth-bolico/pen/oNvmdRo